# Mozilla Firefox Default Font Size

Tags: html, css, firefox

What is the actual default font size in Mozilla Firefox Browser. I tried to look for it at resource://gre-resources/forms.css but it appears undefined. Where could it be located?

Comment: I would think it is in the preferences .. under tab content

Answer (score 1):

You can type in `about:config` in the url-bar and search for "font.size".
This brings up all the different font-size settings for various lang-codes and fixed or variable width fonts. The field `Value` is in px.

More information can be fount in the [docs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Font.)